# How to delete observations in R based criterion that observations have same value?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame, from which I would like to remove observations based on three criteria: x=x, y=y and z>=60.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
                 y=c(2011,2012,2011,2011,2013,2014,2011,2012),
                 z=c(15,15,60,60,15,15,30,15))

> df
  x    y  z
1 1 2011 15
2 1 2012 15
3 2 2011 60
4 2 2011 60
5 3 2013 15
6 3 2014 15
7 4 2011 30
8 4 2012 15
```

The data frame I'm looking for is thus (which one of the x=2 observations is removed doesn't matter):

```
> df1
  x    y  z
1 1 2011 15
2 1 2012 15
3 2 2011 60
4 3 2013 15
5 3 2014 15
6 4 2011 30
7 4 2012 15
```

My first thoughts included using `unique` or `duplicate`, but I cannot seem to understand how to implement it in practice.

Comment: Can you provide some different sample data, because this seems to be just a case for `duplicated` the way it is presented. (`df[!duplicated(df), ]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.  Look for duplicated x and y entries where z is also greater than or equal to 60:

```
df[!(duplicated(df[,1:2]) & df$z >= 60), ]
#  x    y  z
#1 1 2011 15
#2 1 2012 15
#3 2 2011 60
#5 3 2013 15
#6 3 2014 15
#7 4 2011 30
#8 4 2012 15
```